# Changing Label.text from void function in the MainViewController that is called from a separate class

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have a Main View Controller with a button attached to an IBAction called `REFRESH()`.
In the `REFRESH()` action, I call a function in a class that makes an asynchronous request for XML from a WebService and creates an object from that data.

There is another function on the Main View Controller called ``(void) RECEIVED_DATA() which accepts the object that gets created from the XML in my class file.  This function only gets called from my class file after the data has been received back from the server.  At that point, I want to set the text on a label in my Main View Controller.  Unfortunately, I cannot.  I CAN change the label.text in the `REFRESH()` function attached to the button click, but CANNOT change it in the void function that gets called when data is returned from the class file.

Here are the 2 functions:

```
-(void)refresh
{
    funcs *fn = [[funcs alloc]init]; //this is my class file which handles http request and response
    [fn GetData];
}



-(void)received_Data:(DataObject *)x
{
    myLabel.text = [x displayData]; //myLabel is a UILabel on my MainViewController and the displayData function returns an NSString.  It won't even let me use myLabel.text = @"test";  Nothing happens.
}
```

Should I be looking for a way to tie the `RECEIVED_DATA(`) function back into the `viewDidLoad()` function?

UPDATE - 
Another user has indicated that since the data is retrieved by a separate thread, that it cannot affect any of the UI since the UI is running on the main thread.  I will post a separate question to see if anyone has an approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your UILabel myLabel is defined as an IBOutlet you can call

```
self.myLabel.text = @"blah";
```

anywhere in that viewcontroller class.

So is the label defined and hooked up properly as an IBOutlet?

**Edit:**

Turns out this is a case of Class B calling a method in MainViewController. In the method in MainViewController you can update the label text. Use protocol to delegate the method call appropriately.

Comment: I've defined it as an IBOutlet, as a '@property' of the Main View Controller and '@synthesized' it.  I can change the text in viewDidLoad and I can change the text in a function that gets directly called by an IBAction, just NOT by a function that gets called by a separate class.

Comment: separate class? yes you cannot. Its not a variable defined in the separate class

Comment: No, as my post above states, the separate class calls a function in my MainViewController when the class is finished loading data.  That class passes a data populated object to the function in the MainViewController.  The function in the MainViewController receives the data populated object.  I can NSLog all the information from the object in that function with no problem.  The problem is that the function will not change the text in a label. You can clearly see above in my code where I set myLabel.text but it doesn't work.  using self.myLabel.text is no different.

Comment: You need to use protocol. You can google on that. It will help you call a method in MainViewController from the other class. So in the other class you can call mainviewcontroller's method (which sets the label text) in the receive data function.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help, but Googling Protocol is not really any type of answer.  They can be useful, but a protocol is a template that other classes adopt.  It's like saying Google an If..Then..Else statement.  I can already call the method in my MainViewController from the other class.  I can pass data to the method and I can print out that data in the NSLog, but please read this : I CAN'T PRINT OUT THE DATA IN A LABEL.  At the time the method gets called, the UILabel is a NULL object, even though it's accessible since it's an '@property'.

Answer (score 1):

Use Delegation or KVO or NSnotifaction. I understand you problem user.

So,If you create an instance of your main view controller and ask it to set/update the label property, Then that would become a new object with update text.

Since you are using async method,and return value's time frame is non predictable, I suggest you to use NSnotification if you want to make the message passing look simple, Else go for Delegation. Actually try implementing all of them. You will have a clear idea.